# Alias method chain in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, alias-method

In JavaScript, how could you create a new function with the same name as an existing function, while also preserving the original function so it could be called from within the new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the original function into an anonymous function which returns a replacement function which has access to the original function.

E.g.

```
parseInt = (function parseInt(original) {
    return function (x) {
        console.log("original would've returned " + original(x));

        // just random 'new' functionality
        return (x | 0) * 2;
    };
}(parseInt));
```

Example output:

```
>> parseInt(10);
<< original would've returned 10
<< 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to implement *function wrapping*, check the following articles:

- [Wrapping Functions in JavaScript](http://michaux.ca/articles/wrapping-functions-in-javascript)
- [Function Wrapping](http://jsninja.com/Closures#Function_Wrapping)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply assign the old function to a variable with a different name:

```
var old_parseInt = parseInt;

function parseInt(s) {
   return old_parseInt(s) + 1;
}
```